# Make a Power BI report show different things for different people

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on

I have data in a Power BI spreadsheet, where each row is a project. Each Project has a Project Name, Project Assignee, Project Manager, and some more data specific to the project.

Is there a way to make a Power BI report only show a worker's assigned projects? Essentially, each person should only be able to see a row in this spreadsheet if their name is mentioned in it. Is this possible? Maybe I can make something that pulls their Microsoft single sign on (SSO) data to filter the report for them? Comment if you need more details.

MORE EFFICIENT, ALTERNATIVE IDEAS ARE WELCOME! My goal is for each person to see only **their** projects in this Power BI report.

I looked into some possibilities like Microsoft Graph API, but not sure if this is possible. Maybe I need a third party service. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Yes, Row Level Security should meet your requirements, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-rls